# Установить атрибут свойства как только для чтения динамически?

Tags: c#, readonly

У меня есть какой-то класс, в котором множество свойств. Мне необходимо динамически изменить атрибуты некоторых полей, как только для чтения. Дело в том, что установка этого атрибута зависит от входных данных. Как это сделать?

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться это сделать. Вам следует пересмотреть архитектуру приложения таким образом, чтобы динамического изменения доступа к свойству не потребовалось.

Comment: Bulson абсолютно прав, представьте проблемы другого программиста работающего с Вашими классами, которые на лету меняют свое поведение.

Comment: Расскажите поточнее, что именно вы хотите сделать **для чего**. От этого зависит, как именно правильно делать.

Comment: @VladD, например, я рисую графики, если точки по какому-либо графику отсутствуют, то я их график не рисую вообще. У меня есть главный класс, я открываю его экземпляр через propertyGrid и там есть какая-нибудь настройка для графика, который отсутствует. Так вот что я хотела сделать: если график не рисую, то и настройку хотелось бы скрыть.

Comment: Скрыть настройки можно, не вопрос. Но для этого настройку имеет смысл сделать классом `Setting`, и просто присваивать переменной `null` или `new Setting()`, в зависимости от того, нужна настройка или нет. Такой дизайн кажется мне более подходящим.

Answer (score 2):

Можно проверять в сеттере, можно ли устанавливать текущее свойство, и если нельзя, то, например, бросать исключение:

```
private int prop
public int Prop {
    get { return prop;}
    set {
        if(canSetProp)
            prop = value;
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Зря вы такое подсказываете. Динамическое изменение доступа к свойству - это глубоко ущербная практика, т.к. влечет за собой трудно-исправляемые архитектурные изъяны.

Comment: @Bulson, строго говоря, тут нет изменения доступа к свойству. Фактически, в данном случае свойства используются по прямому назначению: позволяют добавить функционал перед получением значения, или перед установкой значений. Для простоты, можно считать это обычной валидацией входных данных.

Comment: ну, кто-то или что-то же будет иметь доступ к этому кранику `canSetProp` и тем самым станет неявным суверенным владельцем доступа к этому сеттеру. Разве нет?

Comment: @Bulson, не обязательно, это может быть приватным полем, то есть, вертеть его может только _сам_ объект.

Comment: Хорошо, если так это и будет.

Comment: Совершенно согласен с уважаемым @Bulson . Проперти крайне вредное изобретение в неумелых ручках. Очень большое недоумение и много мата вызовет возникновение Ехсеption, например, в таком коде myClass.Prop=1.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, в неумелых ручках все что угодно будет вредным изобретением. Недоумение Exception не вызовет, если будет понятный текст ошибки.

Comment: Ладно, еще пара слов. Представьте программиста работающего с чужой плохо документированной dll. Исходя из здравого смысла, нет оснований ожидать выплевывания Exception в строке someClass.someProperty=1 и скобочка try{} catch не ставиться. В процессе тестирования ситуация, когда someClass меняет поведение не встретилась, но она возникла у клиента в момент перевода 100000$. Я полагая, что после этого у многих людей сильно испортится настроение, даже если в "..Exception  будет понятный текст ошибки..."

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, просто не стоит использовать _плохо документированные_ dll :-) Описанная проблема - это проблема конкретной dll, не свойств вообще, и не проверки и выбрасывания исключений в свойствах. Не совсем понял про _скобочка try{} catch не ставиться_

Comment: Вы полагаете, что каждая операция присваивания свойству значения должна помещаться  в try{} catch?. Хорошо, даже если мы это сделали, совершенно не факт, что не корректное поведение всплывет на тестировании. "...не стоит использовать плохо документированные dll.." бывает, что других просто нет. Например современные библиотеки Windows/

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, всегда есть выход: например, можно написать свою. Повторюсь - это проблема _конкретной длл_.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55058/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Comment: Ладно, нас здесь зовут в чат и я думаю, что нового мы уже ничего не скажем. Я лишь считаю, что детишек надо учить только хорошему (в том числе стилю) - плохому они научаться сами.